# cannot launch node of type + can't locate node in package

Tags: ros, roslaunch, docker

I run into some problems trying to run a ROS Kinetic package https://github.com/romarcg/traversability_estimation with nvidia docker.

I started the docker with:

```
nvidia-docker run -it --env="DISPLAY" --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" -v /home/omar/Codes/traversability_docker/traversability-ros-ubuntu-gazebo-pioneer/volume:/volume --name="traversability_gazebo_task" romarcg/traversability-ros-ubuntu-gazebo-pioneer
```

Then after building, I tried to run the package with:

```
roslaunch simulate_traversability_core launch_simulations.launch headless:=true gui:=false world_name:=custom1 dataset_type:=training number_tries:=50
```

The error message occured as:

```
[Err] [RenderEngine.cc:699] Can't open display: :1
[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:97] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:301] Cannot initialize render engine since render path type is NONE. Ignore this warning ifrendering has been turned off on purpose.
[Wrn] [ModelDatabase.cc:339] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
process[robot_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [1325]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [simulate_traversability_core/run_simulation.py]: can't locate node [run_simulation.py] in package [simulate_traversability_core]
[Err] [ModelDatabase.cc:234] No <database> tag in the model database database.config found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]
[Err] [ModelDatabase.cc:293] Unable to download model manifests
[Err] [ModelDatabase.cc:413] Unable to download model[model://sun]
[Err] [SystemPaths.cc:410] File or path does not exist[""]
Error [parser.cc:581] Unable to find uri[model://sun]
Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[script] in element[material] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[rgba] in element[emissive] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
```

I have completely no idea what is going on. I have tried many solutions but none of them work.
Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For the sake of readability... Please use the code formatting tool and not block-quote formatting for commands, and command output.

Answer (score 0):

There are three different errors happening here simultaneously that are causing this.

Here's one:

```
[Err] [RenderEngine.cc:699] Can't open display: :1
```

The code you're trying to run is trying to open a GUI, but it's failing ("Can't open display", ":1" is your monitor). There's a handful of ways to do this and sharing the .x11 directory between the host and container (as you're doing) is one of them. But, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container) stack overflow post for some other approaches.

Then, we get to

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [simulate_traversability_core/run_simulation.py]: can't locate node [run_simulation.py] in package [simulate_traversability_core]
```

This is telling us that it's trying to find the `run_simulation.py` node but can't find it. It was able to find the package, so that implies that things are sourced correctly... The next things to check would be 1) does that file exist and 2) is it an executable?

Finally, there's

```
[Err] [ModelDatabase.cc:234] No <database> tag in the model database database.config found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]
```

This seems to stem from not having downloaded the appropriate models, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105913/connecting-to-gazebo-model-database).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It worked. Please excuse me for replying late. I had a really busy week. I gave up starting a gui of gazebo and the third one was somehow solved. As for the second one, the file exsits and I used chmod +x to make it work. Again, I really appreciate your help. Thank you.